# Always use a class after one condition was defined

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

I have two classes, one does all the work of getting data from a Database(already implemented) and the other from a File(implementing right now).
The thing here is that I want to be able to switch the streaming(Database or File). The process that check whether is Database or File is needed only once.
So, for each method in a class I don't wanna check everytime what should be use when this method is called.
for now, I do as follows:

```
if(IsDataBaseStream())
    Database::execQuery("SELECT * from table");
else //is FileStream
    File::GetAllFrom("Table");
```

This is ugly. I'm refusing to do this.
I thought about callbacks, but that doesnt work between different classes.

Is there a way of not wasting processor work like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a single branch that, once true, is always true? There's virtual no cost.

Comment: @GManNickG Shhh... he *refuses* to do that.

Comment: @GManNickG dont wanna do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [*Strategy Design Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Give both classes a common base with an abstract method taking the data, make a pointer to that base class, and then assign the pointer a file-based or a db-based implementation after a single check.

```
struct BaseStream {
    virtual void process();
};
struct FileStream : public BaseStream {
    virtual void process() {
        File::GetAllFrom("Table");
    }
};
struct DBStream : public BaseStream {
    virtual void process() {
        Database::execQuery("SELECT * from table");
    }
};
...
BaseStream *s;
if (IsDataBaseStream()) {
    s = new DBStream;
} else {
    s = new FileStream;
}
...
s -> process();
```

Comment: or templates or regular functions instead of polymorphism, depending on his use-case.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, you are right: on the most general level, the OP needs an extra level of indirection. The idiomatics of the Strategy Pattern fit well with C++, although function pointers and whatnot can do the job just as well.

Comment: Do they call this the *strategy design pattern*? I personally call this inheritance. (Not trying to picking a fight, but the DP community has a tendency to make up names that make simple things sound more complicated than they are.)

Comment: @larsmans Inheritance (and polymorphism) are the two tools that can be used to implement this design pattern, but they are not the only ones: as Mooing Duck noted above, the same pattern can be implemented without classes or an inheritance hierarchy, because a function pointer is sufficient to give you that extra level of indirection. Design Patterns, however, describe a general approach to dealing with problems of this kind, leaving the implementation aside (the book does suggest an OOP implementation, but that's done to illustrate the concept, not to "cast the implementation in stone").

Comment: It works for me so far. I have tried this before. But got something wrong with the sintax. Tried again, and works just fine now.